# Using .length on a selector while iterating with .each through a JSON file

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to read in the data from a JSON file using jQuery. I'm very new to jQuery, JavaScript, and coding in general, so I've run into a problem that I'm having difficulty solving.

This bit of code: var n = $(element3).length; seems to be the cause of my problem. I'm using nested .each functions to iterate through the JSON file. I'm using the above line to determine the start of the array. However, that code fails when the program reaches a very long string.

I did some research and saw that some people recommended $('#selector').val().length and $('#selector').text().length to people with similar problems to my own. However, neither worked.

While I know that jQuery is used to ensure the code works across browsers, I also wanted to mention in case anyone asks, that I tested this and had the same problem in multiple browsers.

The JSON file is structured like so:

```
{
  "key" : {
    "key" : {
      "key" : "value", //a comment
      "key" : "value", //numbers
      "key" : "value", //numbers
      "key" : "value", //id number
      "key" : [ //question/answer array
        { "key" : "value", "key" : "value" }, 
        {"key" : "value", "key" : "value" },
        ...
       } ]
    },  
...repeats...
  }
}
```

Here is the full code sans HTML that I'm using to read in the JSON file. I will be turning the nested loops into a function after I get the code working properly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('GameData.json', function(data){

    $.each(data, function(index, element){
      console.log("element1: " + index + " : ");

      $.each(element, function(index2, element2){
        console.log("element2: " + index2 + " : ");

        $.each(element2, function(index3, element3){
          console.log("element3: " + index3 + " : " + element3);

          var n = $(element3).length; //This is causing failure

          //lists if n has data
          console.log("element3 data: "+ n)

          if(n != 0){

            $.each(element3, function(index4, element4){
              console.log("element4: " + index4 + " : " + element4);

              $.each(element4, function(index5, element5){
                console.log("element5: " + index5 + " : " + element5);
              });
            });
          }
        });
      });
    });          
  });               
});
```

What I was hoping for was that all of the data would be read in and printed out to the console window. Instead I have the following error:

```
jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: The comment that it's catching on, then:
    at Function.se.error (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2)
    at se.tokenize (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2)
    at se.select (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2)
    at Function.se [as find] (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.find (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2)
    at new k.fn.init (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2)
    at String.<anonymous> (index.html:71)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.html:68)
```

Thank you very much for any and all help!

Comment: Have you tried to console log the element to see exactly what it is?  Actually you're already doing that on `console.log("element3: " + index3 + " : " + element3);`.  So what does it say it is when the error happens?

Comment: The value of element3 at that point is the comment. If I remove the line causing problems, the program runs perfectly fine. It just won't go though the array.

Comment: I'd really just like to know why that particular line is causing problems.